# Limiting the amount of Google doc's forms that can be submitted

Tags: google-forms

I'm arranging an event and I'm using Google Forms so people can sign up. I can only have 100 people and want the sheet to stop accepting new signups to the form when the number is 100. Is this something that we can do with Google Docs Forms?

If you can do this, can you also make it so that the form changes to a message saying that it's now full and you can sign up on a waiting list where you might be able to go?

Comment: This is a good question. I would recommend asking the other part (what you added in the EDIT section) as a separate question though, since they are two different features.

Comment: see this [question][1] in StackOverflow, it will fix your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441750/is-it-possible-to-create-a-limited-registration-signup-form-using-google-docs-fo

Answer (score 1):

Theres a workaround using a spreadsheet to access the form.

A few useful examples are available in this thread;

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=039da52385b9d224&hl=en

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible!
Take a look here to find out how to:
http://www.youpd.org/content/google-forms-pd-sign-session-caps-using-formranger-script-simple-formula