# How to limit each user to fill a form just once?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

Is there any quick way to ensure that each user filled the form just once?

I've already seen this question: [Limiting the amount of Google doc's forms that can be submitted](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/limiting-the-amount-of-google-docs-forms-that-can-be-submitted) . But it doesn't answer my question.